# Бесплатный хостинг с базой MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, хостинг

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

По моему долгому опыту, вряд ли вы найдете бесплатный хостинг с windows, ибо windows денег стоит, а сервер с linux обычно нааамного дешевле.

Посмотрите [тут](http://hosting101.ru/catalog/windows-asp-net-mssql) - может выберете дешевый, за 700-1000р в год.